# how to use prosody and interpret together (SSML)

Tags: java, twilio, ssml

I have a problem how to use in Twilio prosody and interpretAs code combined. 
As 2 speparate tags this works but encapsulation don't. Do you have any ideas how to do this slow peace and interpret as ?

```
SsmlSayAs sayContactPhone = new SsmlSayAs.Builder("+4421222222").interpretAs(SsmlSayAs.InterpretAs.TELEPHONE).build();

SsmlProsody sayContactPhoneProsody  = new SsmlProsody.Builder("+4421222222").pitch("-10%").rate("85%").volume("-6dB").build();
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: It looks to me as though the Twilio helper library doesn't allow you to nest within prosody, but the spec disagrees with that. I will check internally at Twilio to see whether this is intentional or if there is anything that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently the Twilio Java helper library does not support nesting within SSML elements. I have raised this internally and I will let you know when support has been added.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've solved problem by manually manipulate SSML xml. This works perfectly but then helper is useless. I know that some of the tags can't be nested.

Comment: I agree and that's why we are working to fix this in the helper library. Sorry you've had to manually write it for now.

Comment: This is now live in 8.22.1: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/releases/tag/8.22.1